# How can I get AnimateLayoutChanges on a MotionLayout working?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout, android-motionlayout

I want to have my view positions auto-animate using `animateLayoutChanges` with the `LayoutTransition.CHANGING` flag on my `MotionLayout`. Unfortunately I can't get it to work, the views just jump around. I've tried changing the `MotionLayout` to a `ConstraintLayout`, and that works just fine. This makes me think it might be an issue with `MotionLayout` itself, but I'm sure there's got to be some workaround. I need to use a `MotionLayout` specifically for the rest of my app so any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Animatelayoutchanges and MotionLayout are not related and do not work together.

Most animation systems do not work together as each tries to control the movement of objects.

Almost every effect achievable with animateLayoutChanges can be done with MotionLayout.

Comment: Ah, I see. I did some research and found that I could programmatically create a new ConstraintSet with the updated View Constraints, and create a new Transition on my MotionLayout to it, achieving the same result as using animateLayoutChanges. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.